# How to configure a preboot execution environment in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, pxe

I want to configure a ubuntu linux system to act as a preboot execution environment that serves multiple clients to access the boot images from pxe and boot into network. How to configure the ubuntu system as pxe?